# different components taking same CSS styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styles

I created different CSS files for different components and imported them in their respective components but the components have the same styling.
I styled an image for two components differently but after importing the components in app.js the image is styled the same.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 
Implement some code so we can help you..

Comment: seems like you maybe put the desired styles on the img tag and not on a class?

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide some more details or paste the image class which you are using in different components? it will also help other members to understand the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when your react files renders as an HTML file all your styles will be pointing your Html
so If you have two HTML tags with same id or classname they will get the style of the last defined CSS of the particular classname

Comment: Thank you. How can I avoid this from happening?

Comment: use different classnames